# What letter should I use to denote an ideal?

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, notation, ideals

In commutative algebra, there seem to be two rather different notational conventions for ideals: either $I,J, \dots$ or $\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{b}, \dots$.

By itself, it is hardly surprising - after all, lots of other notations vary from source to source. I have, however, come across both conventions in a single script or article on many occasions. And the difference is rather striking: different letter is used, different case, different font...

I find this rather surprising and a little confusing, since usually a single convention is used within a piece of writing. I would very much appreciate any information on where such notational complication comes from. Is one of these conventions preferable (in some circumstances)?

Comment: I learned with $I,J$...

Comment: I like $I$ and $J$ because they require less characters to typeset than $\mathfrak{a}$...although I like $\mathfrak{p}$ for prime ideals over, e.g., $P$.

Comment: Ideally, $\mathfrak{i}$,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Bourbaki in His [*Commutative Algebra*](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Commutative_Algebra.html?id=Bb30CjGW7EAC&redir_esc=y) and His prophets Dieudonné and Grothendieck in [*EGA*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89l%C3%A9ments_de_g%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie_alg%C3%A9brique)  use [Fraktur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur), you have no choice but to do the same.
I shudder to think of the fate befalling heretics and miscreants who would incur His ire by using  Latin letters.

Comment: A very poetic answer, and yet quite informative. I'd say following conventions set by Dieudonné and Grothendieck sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, Feanor: I'm glad you agree with  the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are clear when you define things, and use the same convention consistently, and you don't go out of your way to make the notation ridiculous, nobody cares.

I think whatever you pick (within reason) you'll do fine.

Comment: Well, I care ;) I might be in a minority here, but I do believe a well chosen notation makes understanding a piece of mathematics easier.

Comment: @Feanor If you ask me, just never use $\mathfrak{A}$. I think it looks terrible.

Comment: I won't, I also dislike it. In particular, it is not even obvious which letter it represents unless you know it in advance (it could well be U as well as A, or even M).